# How to retrieve a HTML tag and shorten my code with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My task here is to retrieve a HTML tag with the blockquote code below. I'd tried it by my method but it didn't work and I've changed another way even it wouldn't be the best way as I thought.

**My first attempt and it didn't work:**

```
search_title_temp_1 = $(search_title).closest("tbody").closest("tr").closest("tbody");
search_title_temp_2 = $(search_title_temp_1).find("tr").eq(1);
search_title_temp_2.hide();
```

**This worked with what I need:**

```
search_title_temp_1 = $(search_title).closest("tbody").closest("tr").closest("tbody");
search_title_temp_2 = $(search_title_temp_1).find(".noindex").closest("tr");
search_title_temp_2.hide();
```

---

> **Please let me know:**
>
> 1. What's wrong with my first attempt?
> 2. If you have other solutions to shorten my last code, please let me know about that and any
>      suggestions would be appreciated.

**<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/G3seG/1/)</kbd>**

**HTML:**

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td title="Electric Consumption for May 2013" id="WebPartTitleWPQ3" class="ms-WPHeaderTd">
                             <h3 style="text-align:justify;" class="ms-standardheader ms-WPTitle"><a accesskey="W" href="/Lists/ElectricWaterConsumption"><nobr>
                <span>Electric Consumption for May 2013</span><span id="WebPartCaptionWPQ3"></span>
                </nobr></a></h3>

                        </td>
                        <td>123</td>
                        <td>123</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="" valign="top">
            <div width="100%" class="noindex ms-wpContentDivSpace">123</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("document").ready(function () {
var title = "Electric Consumption for May 2013";
var get_title = $(".ms-WPHeaderTd span");
for (i = 0; i < get_title.length; i++) {
    //alert(get_title.eq([i]).text());
    var search_title = get_title.eq([i]);
    if (search_title.text() == title) {
        alert(search_title.text());
        search_title_temp_1 = $(search_title).closest("tbody").closest("tr").closest("tbody");
        search_title_temp_2 = $(search_title_temp_1).find(".noindex").closest("tr");
        search_title_temp_2.hide();
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Why are you nesting tables like that? Tables should only be used for tabular content.

Comment: **@Oriol**: It's required as my work so that's why I got stuck...

Comment: Please specify which part alone you want to hide and on what condition ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's wrong with my first attempt?

The problem with your first attempt is that `find("tr")` gets all `tr` descendants, not only children. Then `find("tr").eq(1)` is not what you want.

Use this instead:

```
$(search_title_temp_1).children("tr").eq(1);
```

> If you have other solutions to shorten my last code, please let me
>   know about that and any suggestions would be appreciated.

You can ask suggestions about working codes in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

I wouldn't create variables (if you do, declare them with `var`!):

```
$(search_title)
.closest("tbody").closest("tr").closest("tbody")
.children("tr")
.eq(1)
.hide();
```

Comment: Thank you for your additional code. It's awesome at all :-)